# Windows SDK 10 setup won't run

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk, installation

Visual studio won't me download the sdk so I decided to download it manually with the setup.

when I run the setup it just crashes after some seconds.

this is the log called Windows_Software_Development_Kit___Windows_10.0.17763.132_20200409225019:

```
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i001: Burn v3.14.0.1703, Windows v10.0 (Build 17763: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\horro\AppData\Local\Temp\{293B2422-4760-4341-95C6-512E5EA06660}\.cr\WinSDKSetup.exe
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=D:\notworking\WinSDKSetup.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=624 -burn.filehandle.self=688'
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\notworking\WinSDKSetup.exe'
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\notworking\'
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\horro\AppData\Local\Temp\windowssdk\Windows_Software_Development_Kit___Windows_10.0.17763.132_20200409225019.log'
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[1F88:397C][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[1F88:3080][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Launch action is Install
[1F88:3080][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Restart action is Prompt
[1F88:3080][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Resume action is Arp
[1F88:3080][2020-04-09T22:50:19]i000: Display is Full
```

also when trying to install from the installer it says this: `Unknown error (0x80131534) returned code: -2146233036`

vslogs: https://easyupload.io/yfc4f2
Help.

Comment: What is happening when you try it from the visual studio installer? have you tried downloading the newest VS installer?

Comment: @TimBaker Nothing changes. I just get this error: Unknown error (0x80131534)
and this returned value: -2146233036

Comment: @MehdiOuassou, still cannot access the log link. Besides, due to your error, I suggest you could access this path `%LocalAppData%\ Microsoft \ VisualStudio \ 15.0_xxx or 16.0_xxxx(15.0 is VS2017 and 16.0 is VS2019)` and rename the file `privateregistry.bin` or `privateregistry.user.bin` to another custom name. Then test whether the vs installer work. And if it still not works, please try to delete the whole folder `%LocalAppData%\ Microsoft \ VisualStudio \ 15.0_xxx or 16.0_xxxx(15.0 is VS2017 and 16.0 is VS2019)`.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT tried and retried to uninstall it and didn't work.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT can you suggest me a website where I can upload the logs?

Comment: You could try to upload your error log on [onedrive](https://products.office.com/en-sg/onedrive/online-cloud-storage) and share the links with us.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvWzL0UqAxDzgZdeivC1KCikZDvRUA?e=exycnd

Comment: There is an error message `because of the following error: it is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1). Since VS is a 32-bit program and it  usually will not turns out this error. Not sure what you did caused this behavior. Please try to [repair VS in VS installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I tried it, still can't download the sdk :( (same error)

Comment: Finally, please try to uninstall VS and then delete the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` and then reinstall VS agian.

Comment: Did it. Same error :[

Comment: Quite abnormal. And I suspect you don't have installation privileges. And try to contact with your administrator and ask whether you have the privilege to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps:

**Suggestion**

**1)** restart your PC, turn off any anti-virus or third party programs under your PC ,then run your Windows 10 SDK as administrator and then install again.

**2)** also, I wonder why your VS does not allow to install win10 sdk. In general, open `VS Installer`--> `Modify`-->`Individual components`--> select `Windows 10 SDK(10.0.17763.0)` to install.

[image]

**Besides**, you can try to install [the latest win10 sdk](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) if necessary.

**3)** If there is any windows update, please update it.

**In addition**, since your log is insufficient and there is no such error message. Please share the whole log or you could use [collect.exe tool](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/microsoft-vs-net-log-collection-tool/) to collect the installation log and then share it with us so that we could troubleshoot this issue more quickly.

Comment: Here there are the logs of collect.exe tool: https://gofile.io/?c=wpJDFK

Comment: what about this one? https://easyupload.io/yfc4f2
I tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: also when trying to install from the installer it says this:
Unknown error (0x80131534) returned code: -2146233036